# AngularJS service injector error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, typescript

I'm trying to make use of my API with AngularJS; I made a service which I'm now trying to load into a controller, but I'm seeing some errors.

```
Unknown provider: ApiServiceProvider <- ApiService <- ManageIntranetController
```

I'm using TypeScript.

**My service looks like this:**

```
module Services {
    export class ApiService {

        getIntranetItems: (action: string) => any;

        constructor($scope, $http: ng.IHttpService) {

            this.getIntranetItems = (action: string) => {
                return $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "https://localhost:44326/api/intranet/" + action,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                }).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.intranetItems = data;
                }).error(function (msg) {
                    alert("ERROR: " + msg);
                })
            };

        }
    }
}
```

**And my controller looks like this:**

```
/// <reference path="../services/apiservice.ts" />


module Controllers {
    export interface IManageIntranetController extends ng.IScope {

    }    

    export class ManageIntranetController {
        constructor($scope: IManageIntranetController, ApiService: Services.ApiService) {
            console.log(ApiService.getIntranetItems("get"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered the service on your angular module? e.g. `angular.module("myApp", []).service("ApiService", Services.ApiService);`

Comment: Also, you cannot inject `$scope` into a service, that one is only for controllers and directives

Comment: @devqon I did not do that, but now I did I still keep receiving the same errors.. Oh okay, I'll change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error means that it does not know of the service "ApiService". You probably forgot to register it on your module:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("ManageIntranetController", Controllers.ManageIntranetController)
    .service("ApiService", Services.ApiService);
```

Also, your service won't work, because you cannot inject a `$scope` in it. Instead, do something like this:

```
export class ApiService {

    getIntranetItems: (action: string) => any;

    constructor($http: ng.IHttpService) {

        this.getIntranetItems = (action: string) => {
            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "https://localhost:44326/api/intranet/" + action,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });
        };

    }
}
```

and in your controller:

```
ApiService.getIntranetItems("get").then((data) => {
    $scope.intranetItems = data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You still need to register your services/controllers with angular. For example, you register a controller like this:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('myCtrl', MyController); //where MyController is a TypeScript class
```

For services is a bit more complex. You either need to add a static function within your class which returns an instance, call that function when registering the service with angular, or (my personal preference), create a javascript function outside the Class like so:

```
function factory($q: ng.IQService): MyService {
    return new MyService($q);
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('myService', factory);
```